# How can I get data from a push notification coming from Salesforce MarketingCloud using react-native-firebase library as listener?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, salesforce, react-native-firebase, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I have an application that I use react-native in its version 0.64.2. To receive push notifications I use Firebase Messaging from the react-native-firebase library. As sender of push notifications I use Salesforce Marketing Cloud, in my tests pushes work normally and notification is triggered on the user's device, but I can't get the data from these notifications when the app is in the background using the setBackgroundMessageHandler method, with the app in foreground the onMessage method works fine and I can get the notification data but in the background I can't. Another point is that when the notification is sent from Firebase everything works as expected and I can get the notification data both in foreground and in the background.

I've seen on some forums that I need to set the push priority high for Android and use a content_available attribute for iOS for the push to work in the background, but how can I change the push body around Salesforce to add these fields priority and content_available?

dependencies:

```
"@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^12.2.0",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.2.0",
"@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^12.2.0",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^12.2.0",
"react-native-marketingcloudsdk": "^7.4.0",
```

push that comes from Salesforce and I can't get the data:

```
{
   "data":{
      "_h":"pS/soSdadDzWB+Qa+RQaaAAA",
      "_m":"MzE5adNjoxMTdsadQ6MA",
      "_mt":"1",
      "_od":"https://www.teste.com.br/",
      "_r":"a233246d-3c312e-439d-12esafase12",
      "_sid":"SFMC",
      "alert":"Finalizamos nossos testes e agora temos push via iOS. #pracima ",
      "sound":"default",
      "title":"S-U-R-P-R-E-S-A! "
   },
   "from":"9692123278371572",
   "messageId":"0:1627334613526320%5ccc36fef93e3xsdsf",
   "sentTime":1627334613505,
   "ttl":43543534
}
```

push that comes from Firebase and I can get the notification data:

```
{
  "collapseKey": "br.com.teste",
  "data": {},
  "from": "434233544643",
  "messageId": "0:1627504479073910%5ccc36bdf3246fe",
  "notification": {
    "android": {},
    "body": "teste notificacao",
    "title": "teste"
  },
  "sentTime": 1627504479066,
  "ttl": 2002323
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to listen to Marketing Cloud notifications with the firebase library because in IOS Salesforce does not use firebase but APNs, I recommend that you use [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/react-native-push-notification/ios)